# Zipline adventure operators in Jodhpur

Tags: india, adventure, jodhpur

A Lonely Planet guidebook says that it is possible to only ride one line of `Flying Fox` at Mahrangarh fort and their [website](http://flyingfox.asia/jodhpur.aspx?pgid=58) quotes:

> Half an hour for Zip 1 only

but I still can't find the price for only one line nor the info that it is in fact possible to use only that one.

Did anyone here try it or do any of you have any additional information about it?

Comment: Their own site notes that there's a discount for online, in-advance bookings as opposed to just showing up - but they only do the long booking sessions online. The discount does seem substantial so you may want to weigh whether booking the full session in advance is better vs booking a shorter session but paying a similar price for on-the-spot bookings.

Comment: I've read it but it only applies if you book 72 hours in advance and I'm going there today. I hope I'll be able to use only that one zip line. Will let you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed this forum from my google alerts. I am a director of Flying Fox and I'd like to help clarify the situation in Jodhpur.

We've just re-started the single zipline option at Rs 200, and while the actual zip takes 20 seconds we say 30 minutes are required for the harnessing, paperwork, payment, safety briefing, short walk, zip and then harness removal. Similarly, we say 1.5 hours are required for all the above for the 6 zipline tour, for up to 12 people (max group size). If you're in a group of, say, 6, it takes about 1 hour and for a couple about 40 minutes. The Tour costs Rs 1350 for an adult and Rs 1000 for a child or student.

Flying Fox staff at the main gate and at the FF Office should be clear with customers on the zips provided (Single or Tour) and the pricing and we'll remind them on this to ensure such details is being clearly conveyed.

Comment: smart move with the google alerts!

Comment: Awesome, an answer straight from the, uh, airline's mouth!

Answer (score 4):

I went to use the [Flying Fox zipline](http://www.flyingfox.asia/jodhpur.aspx?pgid=58) today and it was a great experience. It was a great fun.

So, to answer my question - the guy next to the ticket counter will tell you that it's not possible to use only one line but that is in fact wrong.

Once you buy your fort ticket, just head straight through the first gate and instead of going left to the fort, go right and down to Chokelao garden, where Flying fox office is. At entrance to the garden, an officer will ask you to pay 30 rupees for it but don't fall for it. I was surprised at how many people actually pay him. You may enter these gardens free of charge.

One zip costs 200 rupees and it doesn't take 30 minutes as quoted at their website but takes rather some 20 seconds. After a short practice run just below the office, you go to line 1 and are back to the office in a couple of minutes.

A better option is to go for a complete run (I wouldn't call it a tour though). It consists of 6 zips and takes around 30 to 40 minutes to finish (not 1.5 hours as advertised). Zip 6 was my favorite one since it's the longest. I was irritated by spinning while on the line but perhaps that was a mistake on my side.

Runs start at 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 14:30 and 16:30 but you can ask them to start earlier and they will most probably say it's OK. They did for me.

You can use your video camera either during your run or you can ask the guys to film you from any of the stops. I don't recommend filming during the runs at zips 2-6 since they're longer and you need a bit more control and you don't need a camcorder to distract you. Film the run at zip 1 and ask the guys to film you during the other ones. Bring your own cord for the video camera in case you drop it.

Tip the guys afterward as they're really fun and enjoy their job and you can feel it. BTW, if you get thirsty, you can buy water there as well (and it's cheaper than elsewhere inside the fort).